# VBA looping through files that meet two criteria

Tags: excel, vba, do-while

Below is working code that is looping through files in a folder based on a user's search criteria. The folder will grow throughout the year to over 1000 files, so rather than looping through all of them every time the macro runs, I would like to add a second criteria that compares the time stamps on the files to a time stamp saved on the file as the last time it was run. `LastUpdateDate` is set up as variable in date format at the top of the module, and the old timestamp is saved to it at the beginning of the code.

I tried this but it left me with a run time error. Is this doable using `Do While`, or is there another format I need to be looking at?  I also tried nesting the date comparison as an `if` statement under the `Do While`, but came up with other errors.

```
Do While FileName <> "" and FileDateTime(FileName) > LastUpdateDate
```

Working code from this section:

```
FileName = Dir(FolderName & "*" & MyCriterion & "*" & ".xl??")   

'Loop through all matching files
Do While FileName <> ""
    'Open the next matching workbook
    Workbooks.Open (FolderName & FileName)
    Sheets("Report Data").Select
    'Call GrabTheData
    GrabTheData

    'Close the workbook
    Workbooks(FileName).Close savechanges:=False

    'Get the name of the next match in folder

    FileName = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur? What are those additional subs, are they relevant?

Comment: Also, what `type` is `LastUpdateDate`? I don't see the declaration. Maybe you're just missing a `CDate()` cast or a `Format()`.

Comment: It gives a file not found when I add the second condition:

Do While FileName <> "" and FileDateTime(FileName) > LastUpdateDate

Runtime error 53


I have LastUpdateDate setup as:

Dim LastUpdateDate As Date

the beginning of the sub asks the user to pick the folder and input a search string. without the second condition it doesn't bring up any errors.

Comment: Have you debugged and set a break point on the line to see the value of `FileName` and checked if the file exists?

Comment: It breaks before FileName gets assigned any value

Comment: so where does it break. you still have kept that to yourself

Comment: Sorry I thought I anwered that one. It breaks at the line beginning with Do While.

Comment: I figured out my issues. It wasn't pulling in the folder path as part of the full file name. I also figured out how to make it do what I need as the nested if statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

## FileDateTime

`FileDateTime` requires the full file path, not just the file name

## Loops and Conditions

`Do While (condition)` stops execution of the block when (condition) is no longer true.

That is, it will stop execution as soon as (condition) is false. I don't believe this is the intended behavior.

Put an `If (condition)` block within the loop itself. This will loop through *every* workbook that matches `MyCriterion`, but only operate on those that match (condition).

## Example (with recommendations)

```
Sub GrabAllData(ByVal FolderName As String, ByVal MyCriterion As String)

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim LastUpdateDate As Date
    Dim wb As Workbook

    LastUpdateDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Parameters").Range("LastUpdateDate").Value 'Named Range called LastUpdateDate on sheet "Parameters" in ThisWorkbook

    'Make sure FolderName ends in a backslash
    If Right(FolderName, 1) <> "\" Then FolderName = FolderName & "\"

    'Get matching files for MyCriterion
    FileName = Dir(FolderName & "*" & MyCriterion & "*" & ".xl??")

    'Loop through all matching files
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If FileDateTime(FolderName & FileName) > LastUpdateDate Then 'FileDateTime requires the full file path, not just the file name
            'Open the next matching workbook - work with the workbook directly, rather than working with ActiveWorkbook, ActiveSheet and Selections
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FolderName & FileName, ReadOnly:=True)

            'Call GrabTheData on the workbook
            GrabTheData wb

            'Close the workbook
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
        'Get the name of the next match in folder
        FileName = Dir
    Loop

    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub

Sub GrabTheData(ByRef wb As Workbook)

    Dim wsOut As Worksheet, wsIn As Worksheet
    Set wsOut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aggregated Data") 'Worksheet called "Aggregated Data" in ThisWorkbook
    Set wsIn = wb.Worksheets("Report Data")

    ' ### Manipulate the data and write to wsOut, no need to work with Selections ###

End Sub
```